# How to update state from static method in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a bottom nav bar that uses this code to switch widgets:

```
    void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndexGlobal = index;
      print(index);
    });
  }
```

And shows the needed widgets in body:

```
body: SafeArea(
    child: new LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            Container con = Container(
                child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(selectedIndexGlobal)
            );
            return con;
          }
      ))
```

I also have a GridView with static children list loaded from Firebase, and tried to apply a GestureDetector to it, to change selectedIndex and update screen state:

```
static getExpenseItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot, BuildContext context) {
    try {
      snapshot.data.documents.sort((a, b) =>
          a.data["order"].compareTo(b.data["order"]));
    } on NoSuchMethodError {}

    return snapshot.data.documents
        .map((doc) =>
    new GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {
        catName = doc["catName"];
        setState(() {
          selectedIndexGlobal = 4;
        });
        },
        child: new Container(
            child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10, bottom: 15),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        border: new Border.all(color: Colors.grey[200],
                        width: 0.8)),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(doc["name"],
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: categoriesFont),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    )
                )
        )

    )
    ).toList();
  }
```

But setState can't be called from a static method, as well as GridView.count doesn't let me use non-static widgets as child. What should I do then to update state on click?

Comment: Why not remove the static keyword?

Comment: You might be able to pass a "callback" to the static function that updates the state from the outside.

Comment: @nonybrighto GridView only accepts a static children list

Comment: @Martin Niederl can you give an example, please?

Comment: i have same issue any idea?

Answer (score 4):

This line will help you get the instance of the Widget State object you need.

All you need access to is the current context object:

```
  _HomeState stateObject = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_HomeState>();

  stateObject.setState(() {
     _tabIndex = index;
  });
```

For this to work, ensure that the context you use to access the State Object is from a child widget of the State object you are trying to find.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though, as you still can't access stateObject inside a static "context"

Comment: @OjonugwaJudeOchalifu yes you can. Just pass the context object into the static method call.